# how to better set up machine for development both in workgroup and Windows domain?

Tags: windows, networking, active-directory, workgroup

I am developer. Initially, at my client(employer) premises I had been given the company's desktop computer with Windows XP Pro SP3 joined to corporate Windows Active Directory domain (AD).

This is situation 1):

- **1) AD computer Windows workstation**  (or, for the sake of discussion, any  Windows workstation operating system ).

Since, for developing, I needed full administration of machine and had rather limited in volume hard disk (of only 20 GB), while having the necessity to setup developing tools ((for ex., Vsial Studio 2008+2010) and servers (for ex., (MS SQL Server 2008 R2, SharePoint Server, etc.), I could not install another Windows. so I had to reformat the hard disk and install fresh

- **2) workgroup Windows XP Pro SP3** (i.e. Windows XP as part of workgroup, not joined to corporate Windows AD).

This resulted in complications to interoperate and develop, test, integrate against AD.

Suppose, I had a bigger hard drive, or for the sake of future similar situations, **what would have been more correct solution ** in order to interoperate, communicate, develop + test + integrate with corporate AD while having full administration of developing machine (without access to corporate AD administration):

**A) to install second (dual boot) workgroup Windows XP (for developing) leaving 1)** for accessing AD resources + testing + integration, so having

- **3) dual-boot machine with 1) + 2)**

or

**B) to hack the single 1) Windows installation?** to simulate/twist between necessities  of isolation+full administration for developing+testing (i.e. having Windows as part of workgroup) vs. necessity of having Windows as part of AD?

Anyway, all setups (configurations), that I could imagine, have the disadvantage of separate booting either into AD machine Windows or into workgroup Windows machine (since it is impossible to have Windows to be both a part of workgroup and AD).

Dual-boot solution 3) also has disadvantage in duplication of quite time-consuming setup, configuration development environment.

**QUESTIONS:**

- Q1) What are the options of merging in one Windows the necessity of isolated development and accessing/development/testing in AD environment?
- Q2) What are the differences in accessing both AD computers and workgroup computers under AD Windows local Administrator vs. under workgroup Windows administrator?

Related questions:

- Q3) https://serverfault.com/questions/169142/interoperating-with-windows-domain-computer-from-workrgroup-windows
- Q4) [how to share the same domain machine account with multi-boot workgroup Windows setup?](https://serverfault.com/questions/168991/how-to-share-the-same-domain-machine-account-with-multi-boot-workgroup-windows-se)

### ----------

Update1:

Sagar advised VirtualBox or VMWare player (which were lost in rantings).

Bart Silverstrim disadvised dual-boot and advised "look into virtualization (which is free in most cases). Snapshots and backups more handy, and you can simulate networks or multiple workstation configurations easily".

GregD again FAQed me though I again could not understand by which one of them. 
GregD wrote:

> "You asked both of those questions
>   yesterday and BOTH are currently at
>   -1. So not only are you asking inscrutable questions, but you aren't
>   interested in having them answered??"

Yes, Iam interested. What should I have understood from 0 answers and multiple downvotes?

### ----------

**Update2:**

Thanks once more to  my ardent readers for close attention  and  closing this question!
Though what was the point since it had been already marked as answered?

**jscott** just added an answer in similar subquestion

- [What are the options for a temporary laptop within a work domain?](https://serverfault.com/questions/170174/what-are-the-options-for-a-temporary-laptop-within-a-work-domain) (What are the options for a temporary laptop within a work domain?):

> "Could the laptop user just connect to
>   his domain desktop via RDP?
>
> He may access file shares on the
>   domain desktop, from the non-domain
>   laptop, provided he uses his domain
>   credentials to connect."

Thanks jscott, once more, I love you!

### ----------

**Update3:**
Oooops, I formatted hard disk and re-installed everything from scratch (100 hours of work) and there was an answer how to convert domained Windows machine to non-domained one:

- [Disable group policy from a workstation [closed]](https://serverfault.com/questions/162691/disable-group-policy-from-a-workstation)

BTW, I reinstalled Windows with approval of company's high management. The problem was that sysadmins did not know how to install Windows in workgroup (they had the burned to CD images with all preset for local AD client setup).

Comment: Based on your history are you deliberately asking inscrutable questions?

Comment: Development targeting MS technologies from MS operating systems are inscrutable? What is expected answer to your question - that I am asking by slip or out of my mind?

Comment: Should the questioner ask only those questions to which he already knows all the answers?

Comment: Your answers and questions are being down voted on a consistent basis, you ask questions that are convoluted and duplicates (of others that you have submitted no less) and you've made comments that sounded like you might actually enjoy losing rep.  I'm actually wondering if you aren't trolling the site.

Comment: Just downvote my question as usual

Comment: And what exactly does "these questions follow but are unattended" mean?  You asked both of those questions yesterday and BOTH are currently at -1.  So not only are you asking inscrutable questions, but you aren't interested in having them answered??

Comment: someone made a cleverbot that can post to SF. :-)

Comment: @VG8-your question doesn't make much sense. Maybe English isn't your primary language, but the as asked, this post is very convoluted and...well, I have no idea what exactly you're trying to do and what your situation is. That's why it's being downvoted by people. Can you edit your question to make it more understandable?

Comment: I've pointed vgv8 to the FAQ before.  I'm not sure s/he is interested in actually having his or her questions answered.

Comment: @Bart: Thanks for your advise. Can you point to me what is not clear in my question and situation?

Comment: Honestly...I'm kind of lost. I think. Are you asking how whether you need to dual-boot a computer as workstation or an active directory server to test an application?

Comment: Dual boot so one is on a workgroup, another is an AD server, or the second one is a client on an active directory domain?

Comment: If so, scrap the dual booting idea and look into virtualization. Snapshots and backups more handy, and you can simulate networks or multiple workstation configurations easily.

Comment: No, I have to use workstation with the need to access+develop+test both against/to corporate AD and in workgroup (to avoid interference with AD networking and/or with AD managent of my machine). I, as developer, do not have access to AD management,

Comment: These rantings and downvotings are by MS AD sysadmins whose religion is that MS AD and overcentralization is the "silver bullet" for all scenarios.

Comment: You sound like you're inviting issues if you start bringing "religion" arguments into this. You're asking how we'd solve the problem...virtualization is free in many cases. It's the first thing I'd look into. Otherwise you might want to look at talking to your IT people for a solution because you're going to have problems with anything that won't let you get into the systems with access your applications need.

Comment: VGV, I recommend dropping your own coin for the hard disk upgrade (they are cheap these days) and ensure you have IT sign off your doing that ahead of time so you can retrieve your hardware upon leaving the organization.  If that's the primary hold up on productivity it may be the very key for you to move forward.

Comment: @Hardryv, I could not respond eralier, since I was banned. I really I brought my own hard disk, this does not solve the problem of having different Windows with duplicate development setups (with each needing up to 40 hours per machine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

His question is really not that hard to understand...

vgv: Can your IT admin not give you administrative control of just your machine? That is how we do it in our office. Each of us has administrative control of our own machines, but we are not allowed to access them from outside the office (no VPN unless you have a company provided laptop - in which case you don't get a desktop anyway).

You don't really need to be in a Workgroup to do development. I'm sure your company can work something out. You just need to explain to your IT person(s) that you need at least some level of administrative access for software development.

As for dual boot, that really does not help you much unless you plan to switch Windows ever time you need to go from developing to sharing some files or accessing something on the network.

The other option you have is to get a bigger hard disk and use a Windows virtual machine that is not connected to the AD. Do your development work on this. It will save you time compared to a dual boot system.

Comment: Yeaah, I constantly read this advises - get a proper OSes, instal Linux sever, Samba, Windows 2008, get a couple of dozens of computers, bug hard disk, RAM, a bunch of virtual machine. This is a big state/federal organization. It requires a year to plan the budget, make a tender and buy something. I shall be on the street waiting even smallest upgrade. Here is a corporate policy. And sysadmins do not care, especailly if it is connected with any non-routine tasks. Also, it is a waste of time to argue with bosses or sysadmins. And I simply cannot do the work of sysadmins and managers

Comment: Really the situation is that to get more 20GB of hard disk, I should first show the results (without which I nobody will even listen about any upgrades0. Most non-dev employees do not require a hard disk more than 20GB and there are corporate norms, policies, non-IT experience and mentality

Comment: If you have the option of dual booting Windows, do you have two licenses or just the one? If you have 2, you can use a free version of VirtualBox or VMWare player. If you have 1, your only option is to dual boot - good luck with that :S

Comment: How do they expect you to show results if you don't have the access you need? That is a bad vicious cycle.

Comment: @vgv 1st comment: If the advice people are giving you doesn't fit into the budget, then find another job. Not to sound cold, but if you cannot get any resources inside a year to be able to do your job, you are in the wrong place.

Comment: I'd have to agree with Dan, from the sounds of it. Polish your resume. If you keep getting the same advice over and over and you can only insist that the issue is with the organization not letting you do XYZ despite the advice from other people working in IT of other organizations and businesses directing you that this is the "smart" way to do it, then there's a non-tech problem.

Comment: If you're trying to say you're developing an app that you need to test against both workgroup and active directory configurations, and you don't have technical access to the system to get the app *you're paid to work on* in order to do it right, then you have a policy problem. Even if that's the case, using VMWare Player or Virtualbox will let you create multiple workstations that you can configure as you want without screwing up your computer and work as a virtual sandbox for testing. No "religion" involved. There's a reason you keep getting this advice.

Comment: @Bart Silverstrim and @Dan. Can you give me links besides this question where I "keep getting the same advice over" and which one? And where do I insist?

Comment: @Sagar, thanks! Your advices on "VirtualBox or VMWare player" are valuable, technical, helpful to others and should not be lost in this ranting. You should have updated/edited your answer to be voted by others. I am not sure if I can vote-up more than once.

Comment: @vgv8-you said in your first comment to this answer "I constantly read this advises" before continuing on to lament that your federal/state boss doesn't allow such upgrades without hassle, so why are you quoting the keep getting the same advice as if we're pulling it out of thin air? And then tell Sagar that the virtualbox/vmware player suggestion is valuable, etc. despite the fact that I brought it up in the comment originally? And you have the nerve to ask how your posts are confusing and convoluted? Nevermind. Done with you.

Comment: "Bart_Silverston, I did not lament and not about boss. Had you already written the same in weblog of Barack Obama? He seems also has to wait a long for Senate quorum to get approvals on his projects and money requests?

Comment: @Bart Silverstrim, there is only one straight answer to a straight question. I reread all your comments and upvoted your valuable/helpful ones (except those on religious wars). Also, you are 1 of two real helpers mentioned in the main post